# How to make the generic FailsafeExecutor reusable

Tags: java, generics, java-failsafe

I am using the [FailSafe](https://failsafe.dev/)  library to handle failures and retries.

The current implementation creates the generic `FailsafeExecutor` on each run -

```
var result = Failsafe.with(Collections.singletonList(retryPolicy))
  .with(scheduler)
  .<R>getAsyncExecution(execution ->
    doSomething(x, y));
```

`FaileSafe.with` definition -

```
public static <R, P extends Policy<R>> FailsafeExecutor<R> with(P outerPolicy, P... policies)
```

Since this is called on a critical path, I would really like to avoid this (the recreation of the object).

I tried initiating the `FailsafeExecutor` on the class level (the class is not generic) with a `<?>` -

```
private final FailsafeExecutor<?> executor;
```

but then when calling the executor I receive -
`Type parameter 'R' is not within its bound; should extend 'capture<?>'`

Is there any way to get over this? Some kind of way I could make this object reusable?
(same with the RetryPolicy, but I guess if there is a solution for the first it would apply for the policy as well)

Thanks.

Comment: "*Since this is called on a critical path, I would really like to avoid this.*" - Why exactly do you want to avoid this? --- "*... but since it is generic and it does not know it's type until runtime.*" - This is not how generics works. The types are defined at compile-time, and, due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the types are gone at runtime.

Comment: @Turing85 This function is a part of a library that will be used on a very high scale. I wouldn't want to create the object each time it reaches this code.
Regarding the second part - I have edited the post. I hope it makes more sense

Comment: @Turing85 I guess the question is more about an alternative for a reusable object within the library itself. You might want to configure an object with non-generic policies and reuse that for different types.